# Doesn't add UISearchController

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I am trying to programmatically add a UISearchController to a UICollectionViewController.

But it doesn't work. What's the matter?
It will not appear on the simulator

```
class PicturesCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSearchBar()
    }
    
    private func setupSearchBar() {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }

    // ... numberOfItemsInSection && cellForItemAt indexPath 
}
```

Comment: Did you have navigation controller in PicturesCollectionViewController?

Comment: @ScorpiCon Thank! I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that I am testing on a simulator and did not think about it

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```